# Вложенные деревья javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как добавить это дерево в select list чтобы количество "-" знаков возле имени папки было эквивалентно количеству родителей (или что то же самое глубине уровня)?

Пример, как должен выглядеть список для конкретно этого дерева:

```
Folder1    
-Folder2  
--Folder6  
---Folder9  
---Folder12  
-Folder3  
--Folder4   
---Folder7  
----Folder8  
-----Folder11  
---Folder13  
--Folder4  
Folder10
```

У меня одну часть правильно выводит, а вторую неправильно.

```js
var twigs = {
  "data": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Folder1",
      "parentId": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Folder2",
      "parentId": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Folder3",
      "parentId": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Folder4",
      "parentId": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Folder5",
      "parentId": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Folder6",
      "parentId": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "Folder7",
      "parentId": 4
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "Folder8",
      "parentId": 7
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "name": "Folder9",
      "parentId": 6
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "name": "Folder10",
      "parentId": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "name": "Folder11",
      "parentId": 8
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "name": "Folder12",
      "parentId": 6
    },
    {
      "id": 13,
      "name": "Folder13",
      "parentId": 4
    }
  ]
};

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $("#add").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var optionName = $("#title").val();
    var optionValue = twigs.data.length + 1;
    $("<option/>").attr('value', optionValue).text(optionName).appendTo("#parent");
    if ($("#parent").val() == 0) {
      twigs.data.push({
        id: twigs.data.length + 1,
        name: optionName,
        parentId: 0
      });
    } else {
      twigs.data.push({
        id: twigs.data.length + 1,
        name: optionName,
        parentId: parseInt($("#parent").val())
      });
    }

    $("#tree").html("");
    var tree = createTree(twigs.data);
    $('#tree').append(tree);
    $("#parent").val("");
  });

  function createTree(data, parentId) {

    parentId = parentId || 0;
    var items = data.filter(function(elem) {
      return elem.parentId === parentId;
    });

    if (items.length === 0) return null;

    var tree = $('<ul>').addClass('tree');
    tree.append(
      items.map(
        function(elem) {
          $("<option/>").attr('value', elem.id).text(new Array(parentId + 1).join("-") + elem.name).appendTo("#parent");
          var li = $('<li>').append(
              $('<img src="images/folder.png">').addClass('state')
            ).append(
              $('<a>').html("<span>" + elem.name + "</span>").attr('id', elem.id).addClass('item')
            ),
            nestedTree = createTree(data, elem.id);

          if (nestedTree !== null) {
            li.append(nestedTree)
              .addClass('collapse')
          }
          return li;
        }
      )
    );
    return tree;
  }

  var tree = createTree(twigs.data);

  $('#tree').append(tree);

  $('#tree')
    .on('click', '.item', function() {
      $('.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
    })
    .on('click', '.state', function() {
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('collapse expand');
    })

});
```

```css
img {
  width: 20px;
}

select {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 173px;
}

button#add {
  width: 173px;
  height: 20px;
}

ul.tree {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}

.active {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.state {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1em;
}

.collapse>.state::after {
  content: '+';
}

.expand>.state::after {
  content: '-';
}

.collapse>ul {
  display: none;
}

.expand>ul {
  display: block;
}

.item {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="title">Title:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="title" name="title"><br>
<select id="parent">
        <option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
    </select><br>
<button id="add">Add</button><br>
<div id="tree"></div>
```

Comment: В код не вчитывался сильно, но предлагаю следующее: в createTree идет третий параметр prefix. изначально он prefix='', когда рекурсивно вызывается createTree третим параметром передаем prefix + '-' и вставляем его перед каждым элементом

Comment: @Skywave сейчас попробую

Comment: @Skywave не работает(( у всех дочерних элементов только один символ.

Comment: вставь в разметку вместо php сразу код, который он возвращает, тогда можно будет код перенести в сниппет, запустить и посмотреть что и как работает

Comment: @Grundy я не очень понимаю о чем идет речь, новичок на этом сайте

Comment: В части, перед которой у тебя написано `PHP:`, есть php код и строчка `var twigs = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>`. Вставь вместо `<?php echo json_encode($array); ?>` - то что в итоге отдает php. Тогда у тебя получится чистый html, и твой пример можно будет запустить непосредственно в вопросе

Comment: @АлександрКайзер, перенес твой код в сниппет - вроде бы все именно так как тебе и надо отображается?

Comment: @Grundy спасибо большое) а то я не мог разобраться. Ну оно выводит количество минусов по айдишнику родителя, а мне надо по уровню вложенности

Comment: @Grundy там где совпадает id родителя и уровень вложенности - там правильно, а где не совпадают - неправильно.

Comment: так, ты про какие минусы говоришь? который в дереве ( ul/li ) или которые ты как `option` добавляешь в выпадающий список?

Comment: @Grundy про минусы для выпадающего списка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое решение: добавить в функцию третий параметр, отвечающий за уровень и увеличивать его при передаче в рекурсивный вызов, например так

```
function createTree(data, parentId, depth) {

    ...
    depth = depth || 0;
    ...

    $("<option/>").attr('value', elem.id).text(new Array(depth + 1).join("-") + elem.name).appendTo("#parent");
    ...
    var nestedTree = createTree(data, elem.id, depth + 1);
    ...
}
```

```js
var twigs = {
  "data": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Folder1",
      "parentId": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Folder2",
      "parentId": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Folder3",
      "parentId": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Folder4",
      "parentId": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Folder5",
      "parentId": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Folder6",
      "parentId": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "Folder7",
      "parentId": 4
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "Folder8",
      "parentId": 7
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "name": "Folder9",
      "parentId": 6
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "name": "Folder10",
      "parentId": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "name": "Folder11",
      "parentId": 8
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "name": "Folder12",
      "parentId": 6
    },
    {
      "id": 13,
      "name": "Folder13",
      "parentId": 4
    }
  ]
};

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $("#add").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var optionName = $("#title").val();
    var optionValue = twigs.data.length + 1;
    $("<option/>").attr('value', optionValue).text(optionName).appendTo("#parent");
    if ($("#parent").val() == 0) {
      twigs.data.push({
        id: twigs.data.length + 1,
        name: optionName,
        parentId: 0
      });
    } else {
      twigs.data.push({
        id: twigs.data.length + 1,
        name: optionName,
        parentId: parseInt($("#parent").val())
      });
    }

    $("#tree").html("");
    var tree = createTree(twigs.data);
    $('#tree').append(tree);
    $("#parent").val("");
  });

  function createTree(data, parentId, depth) {

    parentId = parentId || 0;
    depth = depth || 0;
    var items = data.filter(function(elem) {
      return elem.parentId === parentId;
    });

    if (items.length === 0) return null;

    var tree = $('<ul>').addClass('tree');
    tree.append(
      items.map(
        function(elem) {
          $("<option/>").attr('value', elem.id).text(new Array(depth + 1).join("-") + elem.name).appendTo("#parent");
          var li = $('<li>').append(
              $('<img src="images/folder.png">').addClass('state')
            ).append(
              $('<a>').html("<span>" + elem.name + "</span>").attr('id', elem.id).addClass('item')
            ),
            nestedTree = createTree(data, elem.id, depth + 1);

          if (nestedTree !== null) {
            li.append(nestedTree)
              .addClass('collapse')
          }
          return li;
        }
      )
    );
    return tree;
  }

  var tree = createTree(twigs.data);

  $('#tree').append(tree);

  $('#tree')
    .on('click', '.item', function() {
      $('.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
    })
    .on('click', '.state', function() {
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('collapse expand');
    })

});
```

```css
img {
  width: 20px;
}

select {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 173px;
}

button#add {
  width: 173px;
  height: 20px;
}

ul.tree {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}

.active {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.state {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1em;
}

.collapse>.state::after {
  content: '+';
}

.expand>.state::after {
  content: '-';
}

.collapse>ul {
  display: none;
}

.expand>ul {
  display: block;
}

.item {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="title">Title:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="title" name="title"><br>
<select id="parent">
        <option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
    </select><br>
<button id="add">Add</button><br>
<div id="tree"></div>
```

Comment: даааа))спасибо большое, я знал что именно ты меня выручишь)) жаль что заголовок модераторы отредактировали.

Comment: @АлександрКайзер, не модеры, а участник. И не стоит впредь обращаться к кому-то лично, мы здесь как геты - лично нет никого, но в целом получается сообщество.

Comment: @Aid ок, буду в курсе, извиняюсь